# click to submit form on other angular file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am new to angularjs and node world. I am trying to implement functionality where I have one HTML form where user can search some data from some API and it does get's result on the same where below section. Whenever user search the data, search history gets stored under some other database as well. I have one more search history page where all the user search history gets stored and display's it correctly for that particular user. Now I want to have hyperlink on that search history and whenever user clicks on that search history the same search should happen again. Now my question is, I am getting search result on html form submit than how to I replicate the same on href from some different search history html?

Below is the sample code I have in place. Please help on how to implement this hyperlink and repeat the same search?

search.html:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <h2>Search Data</h2>        

    <form>
        <div>
            <div>                   
            <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" ng-click="getSearchData()">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<!--Display data what we received once user clicks on search button-->
    <div ng-repeat="search in searchData">          
        {{search}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have simple search history page as below.

history.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="searchHistory in list">
    {{searchHistory}}
</div>
```

I can add some ng-click to this but I was not able to make this working. Basically as I have mentioned above, whenever user click on any of the search history, it should make the same search again but I am not sure how to submit html form under search.html when user clicks on history.html?

Comment: Right now it's not really clear what you are trying to do.  Are you asking how to execute `getSearchData()` but using `searchHistory` instead of `search`?  Or are you trying to make `searchHistory` into a hyperlink that launches the `search.html` page and automatically fills it in with the `search`?

Comment: @Claies, thank you for looking into this. Actually I want to do second where I am trying to make searchHistory into a hyperlink that produces the search.html page and automatically fills it in with the search or searchData and it displays the result for that particular searchHistory record.

Comment: that would be a multiple stage process, involving generating the search history as a URL parameter, calling the search page, modifying the search page to accept the URL parameter, and initializing the form to automatically run the search function with the accepted URL parameter value.  Any piece of this process in particular that you need more help with?

Comment: Do you know any example that I can check here to do what you just explained? I know that I can pass param to getSearchData method and use that further to make the request to actual search API but I am not sure how to render that to search.html and display result there?